# Add class to elements with same id on click, remember class on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a page that contains multiple inner pages - a front page that displays by default, and child pages which display when relevant links on the front page are clicked.

What I am trying to achieve is that when a `page-link` element is clicked, the class `active-page` is added to the inner page with the same id, and the `intro` section has a class `off-canvas` added, & the active page is set in localStorage - so that if for any reason the page is refreshed, the last page that was being viewed is displayed.

Alternatively, when a `lnk-rtn-home` element is clicked, the current `inner-page` should lose the active page class while `front-page` loses its off-canvas class. Likewise, this should update the localStorage.

The HTML structure is as follows:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <section id="intro" class="front-page row">
      {{ content }}
      <a data-id='about-me' class='page-link'>About Me</a>
      {{ more content }}
      <a data-id='contact' class='page-link'>Contact</a>
    </section>

    <section id="about-me" class="inner-page row">
      {{ content }}
      <a class='lnk-rtn-home'>Return Home</a>
    </section>

    <section id="contact" class="inner-page row">
      {{ content }}
      <a class='lnk-rtn-home'>Return Home</a>
    </section>

  </div>
</body>
```

The current JS stands at

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var activePageSet = localStorage.getItem('current-page');

// Check if an active page has been set
if (activePageSet) {
    $('#' + activePageSet).addClass('active-page');
    $('#intro').addClass('off-canvas');
}

// Links to inner pages
$('.page-link').click(function() {
    var currentPage = $(this).data("id");
    $('#' + currentPage).addClass("active-page");
    $('#intro').addClass('off-canvas');
    localStorage.setItem('current-page', JSON.stringify(currentPage));
});

// Link to return home
$('.lnk-rtn-home').click(function() {
    if ($('.inner-page').hasClass('active-page')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active-page');
        localStorage.removeItem('current-page');
    }

    $('#intro').removeClass('off-canvas');
});

});
```

No amount of playing around with this has got it working, and at this stage I'm lost as to how to achieve it.

Comment: **ID**'s should be unique, do you mean `id` to match  the `dataset` of `data-id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to select right element for hasClass condition.

You can use a parent, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Links to inner pages
$('.page-link').click(function() {
    var currentPage = $(this).data("id");
    $('#' + currentPage).addClass("active-page");
    $('#intro').addClass('off-canvas');
    //localStorage.setItem('current-page', JSON.stringify(currentPage));
});

// Link to return home
$('.lnk-rtn-home').click(function() {
  var jqSection = $(this).parent();
    if (jqSection.hasClass('active-page')) {
        jqSection.removeClass('active-page');
        localStorage.removeItem('current-page');
    }

    $('#intro').removeClass('off-canvas');
});

});
```

Here is an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/xfgHpWdDpnDTyjLYYrGd?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved with using only 1 class. You have made your code more complex by using 2 classes. I replaced `.active-page` and `.off-canvas` with the class `.hidden`. This gives a simpler code to follow.

```js
var activePageSet = null; //localStorage.getItem('current-page');
//not able to do localStorage in snippet

// Check if an active page has been set
if (activePageSet) {
    $('#' + activePageSet).removeClass('hidden');
    $('#intro').addClass('hidden');
}

// Links to inner pages
$('.page-link').click(function() {
    var activePageId = $(this).data("id");
    
    $('#' + activePageId).removeClass("hidden");
    $('#intro').addClass('hidden');
    
    //localStorage.setItem('current-page', JSON.stringify(activePageId));
});

// Link to return home
$('.lnk-rtn-home').click(function() {
    var activePage = $(this).parent();
    activePage.addClass('hidden');
    $('#intro').removeClass('hidden');
    
    //localStorage.removeItem('current-page');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <section id="intro" class="front-page row ">
      {{ intro content }}
      <a data-id='about-me' class='page-link'>About Me</a>
      {{ more content }}
      <a data-id='contact' class='page-link'>Contact</a>
    </section>

    <section id="about-me" class="inner-page row hidden">
      {{ about content }}
      <a class='lnk-rtn-home'>Return Home</a>
    </section>

    <section id="contact" class="inner-page row hidden">
      {{ contact content }}
      <a class='lnk-rtn-home'>Return Home</a>
    </section>

  </div>
```